# Calculation cost - FIFO - PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerquery, fifo

Good morning all,

I have a bunch of tables where I calculate the stock in and out with the cost. I am calculating the cost unit prices by average.

Is there a way to calculate the cost price by FIFO (first in first out) principle with PowerQuery ?

Clarification :

I have 4 tables

Products

| Code | Description | Unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ET001 | MEAT | kg |
| ET002 | CHICKEN | kg |
| SEB001 | ONION | kg |
| SEB002 | POTATO | kg |
| SEB003 | CARROT | kg |
| KURU001 | RISE | kg |
| KURU002 | WHEAT | kg |
| KURU003 | CHICKPEAS | kg |
| KURU004 | BEAN | kg |

Stock In Table

| Date In | Code | Code Name | Quantity In | Unit | Unit Price | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30.05.2023 | et001 | MEAT | 100 | kg | 2,500.00 | 250,000.00 |
| 30.05.2023 | et002 | CHICKEN | 50 | kg | 750.00 | 37,500.00 |
| 30.05.2023 | SEB001 | ONION | 150 | kg | 200.00 | 30,000.00 |
| 30.05.2023 | SEB002 | POTATO | 75 | kg | 450.00 | 33,750.00 |
| 30.05.2023 | SEB003 | CARROT | 115 | kg | 600.00 | 69,000.00 |
| 31.05.2023 | et002 | CHICKEN | 120 | kg | 1,500.00 | 180,000.00 |
| 31.05.2023 | et002 | CHICKEN | 150 | kg | 2,750.00 | 412,500.00 |

Stock Out Table

| Date Out | Code | Code Name | Quantity Out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31.05.2023 | et001 | MEAT | 25 |
| 31.05.2023 | et002 | CHICKEN | 170 |
| 31.05.2023 | seb003 | CARROT | 35 |
| 31.05.2023 | seb002 | POTATO | 36 |
| 31.05.2023 | seb001 | ONION | 90 |

Dates Range

| First Day | Last Day |
| --- | --- |
| 01.05.2023 | 31.05.2023 |

I am calculating the balances and total cost between the dates with average unit prices in Power Query. The result is :

| Code | Code Name | Total In | Total Out | Balance Stock | Avg. Price | Total Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ET001 | MEAT | 100.00 | 25.00 | 75.00 | 2,500.00 | 62,500.00 |
| ET002 | CHICKEN | 320.00 | 170.00 | 150.00 | 1,968.75 | 334,687.50 |
| SEB001 | ONION | 150.00 | 90.00 | 60.00 | 200.00 | 18,000.00 |
| SEB002 | POTATO | 75.00 | 36.00 | 39.00 | 450.00 | 16,200.00 |
| SEB003 | CARROT | 115.00 | 35.00 | 80.00 | 600.00 | 21,000.00 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | 452,387.50 |

What I am trying to calculate the average unit price by FIFO principle in Power Query, without formulas, VBA etc...

The expected result should be :

| Code | Code Name | Total In | Total Out | Balance Stock | Avg. Price | Total Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ET001 | MEAT | 100.00 | 25.00 | 75.00 | 2,500.00 | 62,500.00 |
| ET002 | CHICKEN | 320.00 | 170.00 | 150.00 | 1279.41 | 217,500.00 |
| SEB001 | ONION | 150.00 | 90.00 | 60.00 | 200.00 | 18,000.00 |
| SEB002 | POTATO | 75.00 | 36.00 | 39.00 | 450.00 | 16,200.00 |
| SEB003 | CARROT | 115.00 | 35.00 | 80.00 | 600.00 | 21,000.00 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | 335,200.00 |

You can find the powerquery codes in the file.

[Sample File](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnyfkbrJQyhJrXyeD61z9ZANQjgd?e=uQxgDV)

Thanks

Comment: The sample code found from Melissa Feb22 is fairly good and similar to what I would create https://forum.enterprisedna.co/t/fifo-cost-valuation-for-the-sales-transactions/22760/3

Comment: Is there any reason you are wanting to transform this in Power Query instead of the data model itself (DAX)?

Comment: @horseyride thank you but i am not that good to implement it into my case (((

Comment: @Luke_0 there is no special reason, if it is easier in the data model, i can use it also.

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept is to create a running total column on the stock-in table by product code, and a running total column on the stock-out table by the product code. Then, perform a left-outer join of the stock-in table onto the stock-out table. Filter where:

1. Running total stock-out is ***greater than*** the prior running total stock-in (running total stock-in minus this record stock-in).
2. Running total stock-in is ***less than*** the prior running total stock-out (running total stock-out minus this record stock-out).

The stock-out quantity on each remaining record should be set to the minimum of the following four values:

1. Stock-out quantity
2. Stock-in quantity
3. Running total stock-in less prior running total stock-out
4. Running total stock-out less prior running total stock-in

Then just multiply the resultant quantity by the stock-in cost to get the total cost-value. Note, this will break each stock-out record into multiple records for each applicable cost layer.

Comment: I calculated the Running Totals. then I filtered as you wrote and only one row left `each ([StockOut.Running Total] >= [Running Total] and [Running Total]< [StockOut.Quantity Out] ` what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: [revised file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnyfkbrJQyhJrXyeD61z9ZANQjgd?e=hcdS1B)

Comment: Checked out your file, small typo in my answer, first filter criteria should have been greater than, not greater or equal to. Couple things in your file: 1)  your resultant quantity didn't seem to have the minimum logic. You can do this with a List.Min({}) function. 2) I think your filter logic didn't quite match mine. Be sure you are using *prior* running totals where indicated.